# Find all properties which exists in collection and has not-null or not empty value

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I'm trying to find using Robo3T in my collection all properties which have property `InternalCode` as not null and not empty

```
db.getCollection('db1.customer').find({ InternalCode : { $exists: true, $ne: null } })
```

this will return all document which has that property and which are set to not null.

> How to deal with scenarios where I want nonempty and not null value?

Comment: have you tried `$nin:[null,""]`

Comment: yeah, just tried moment ago and it's working.

Comment: I will make this as an answer to help people who seek this kind of question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get not empty and not null,

```
db.getCollection('db1.customer').find({ InternalCode : { $exists: true, $nin:[null,""] } })
```